# opencv frame difference Unhandled exception

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to do frame difference with below code. when I run it it show only first frame and crashes . can you help to see why this is happening

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()

{
cv::Mat frameCurrent, framePrev;
cv::Mat  frameAbsDiff=;
//prepare Mats
VideoCapture cap("e.mp4");

cap >> frameCurrent;

framePrev = cv::Mat::zeros(frameCurrent.size(), frameCurrent.type());

cvtColor(frameCurrent, frameCurrent, CV_BGR2GRAY);


frameCurrent.copyTo(framePrev);

while (1)
{
    if (frameCurrent.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Frame1Message->End of sequence" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    cv::absdiff(frameCurrent, framePrev, frameAbsDiff);

    imshow("frameCurrent", frameCurrent);
    imshow("frameAbsDiff", frameAbsDiff);


    if (waitKey(90) == 27)
        break;

    frameCurrent.copyTo(framePrev);
    cap >> frameCurrent;
}
}
```

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::arithm_op, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 1287

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second frame this problem will happen :
`frameCurrent` is RGB(3-Channel) while `framePrev` is Gray(1 Channel). You may debug and make sure.
To solve it:
change :

```
  frameCurrent.copyTo(framePrev);
  cap >> frameCurrent;
```

to

```
  frameCurrent.copyTo(framePrev);
  cap >> frameCurrent;
  cvtColor(frameCurrent, frameCurrent, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments , I need the frames to be gray scaled . The original video is RGB video .

Comment: as you see the code above just black output no difference result

Comment: Yes you are substracting the image from its copy so bo diffrence

Comment: Make getting new frame in the begining of the while and keep the copy at the end

Comment: Thanks , now it is working , is   frameCurrent.copyTo(framePrev);   is ok ? or should I use another approach

Comment: I think clone works will too. I am on mobile and do not have reference gor the diffrence you may search for it and do not forget to accept if your problem solved.. good luck

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should add `cvtColor(frameCurrent, frameCurrent, CV_BGR2GRAY);` after the last `cap >> frameCurrent;`. Since you are using a single channel image by using `CV_BGR2GRAY` you need to be coherent and keep using it in all the frames, otherwise you will be trying to apply the subtraction between a 3 channel image and a single channel one.

Comment: or remove the grayscale conversion in the beginning.

Comment: Sometimes when frames are subtracted is better to use one channel, this technique is used in movement detection, and a single channel is enough.

Comment: sure that's true (although movement detection might be better with color information - depends on the scenario), but the user didn't tell whether he likes to use grayscale or color in the end, so there are two different ways to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code to the following according to your suggestions , when I run , it doesn't show the result of difference in

imshow("frameAbsDiff", frameAbsDiff);

it is just black screen

```
int main()

{
   cv::Mat frameCurrent, framePrev;
   cv::Mat  frameAbsDiff;
//prepare Mats

VideoCapture cap("m.mp4");
cap >> frameCurrent;
cvtColor(frameCurrent, frameCurrent, CV_BGR2GRAY);

frameCurrent.copyTo(framePrev);

while (1)
{
    if (frameCurrent.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Frame1Message->End of sequence" << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    cv::absdiff(frameCurrent, framePrev, frameAbsDiff);

    imshow("frameCurrent", frameCurrent);
    imshow("frameAbsDiff", frameAbsDiff);


    if (waitKey(90) == 27)
        break;

    cap >> frameCurrent;

    cvtColor(frameCurrent, frameCurrent, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    frameCurrent.copyTo(framePrev);


}
}
```